# Passing Arrays as Parameters and Returning Them in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, delete-operator

```
// createArray_1 returns the array as a return value
double* createArray_1( ) {
    return new double [ 10 ];
}

// createArray_2 returns the array from the parameter list
// (using a reference parameter)
void createArray_2( double*& arr ) {
    arr = new double [ 10 ];
}

// createArray_3 returns the array from the parameter list
// (without using a reference parameter but simulating
// pass-by-reference using a pointer)
void createArray_3( double** arr ) {
    *arr = new double [ 10 ];
}

// What is wrong with the following two functions?
// void incorrectCreateArray_1( double* arr ) {
// arr = new double [ 10 ];
//}
// double* incorrectCreateArray_2( ) {
// double arr[ 10 ];
// return arr;
// }
```

And we have the main function:

```
int main() {
   double* D;
   D = createArray_1();
   delete [] D;
   createArray_2( D );
   delete [] D;
   createArray_3( &D );
   delete [] D;
   return 0;
}
```

Can you help me understand why create_array2 and create_array3 are correct whereas incorrectCreateArray_1 and incorrectCreateArray_2 are wrong?

To me, incorrectCreateArray_1 should be fine because we are passing a pointer, and then assign a double array of size 10 to it, which seems correct.

On the other hand, incorrectArray_2 returns a double pointer, which should be fine because arr points to a double array, which also seems correct.

Comment: Please use `std::vector` to solve many problems at once. Explicit use of `new` and `delete` is discouraged since C++11/14 (and in case of arrays for a longer time - since std::vector was introduced).

Comment: Generally speaking, arrays are a C construct that is best avoided entirely in C++. Passing `std::vector` (or, if really necessary, `std::array`) is much safer and more intuitive.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions. I will keep that in mind. But, I think understanding what is wrong with this code can help me better comprehend pointers in entirety.

Comment: `incorrectCreateArray_1` changes just the parameter (which is a copy of the passed pointer) not the original pointer.  `incorrectCreateArray_2` returns a pointer to the local variable which is destroyed when the function returns and leads to a dangling pointer.

Comment: Problem is scope and lifetime of variables. `incorrectCreateArray_1` modyfies local value, so result is not passed outside.  `incorrectArray_2` uses local array which lifetime ends when function exits, so returned pointer is dangling leading to undefined behavior.

Comment: @yigitskylab Well, again -- pointers aren't really "the way to go" in C++. Virtually all the places you would use a pointer in C are better handled by references in C++. Explaining pointers is easier done when not looking at a code sample where the use of pointers is a terrible idea to begin with. (Using `new` outside a constructor is *bad*. If there is an exception somewhere, or the user of your function(s) forgets to clean up, you have a resource leak. `new` in constructors, `delete` in destructors. Better yet, use smart pointers. Better than that even are standard containers.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void incorrectCreateArray_1( double* arr ) 
{
    arr = new double [ 10 ];
}
```

is incorrect because you receive a pointer (uninitialized) and you make it point somewhere else. But only the `arr` pointer, local to this function, gets changed. The calling code still keeps its (uninitialized) pointer.

```
double* incorrectCreateArray_2( ) 
{
    double arr[ 10 ];
    return arr;
}
```

is incorrect because you return a pointer to a local object (`arr`) which will not be valid to access after the function returns.